# IE: Background Image does not display. Browser repaints on hover?

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

So this is one of the strangest IE bugs I have come across, and it's happening in IE11!

I have a simple element that looks as follows:

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header><h1>Hello World</h1></header>
        <div class="image" style='background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Left_side_of_Flying_Pigeon.jpg");'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

.article {
    height:200px;
    background:aliceblue;
}

.wrapper {
    height:100%;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}

header, .image {
 display:table-row;
    width:100%;
}

header {
    background:red;
    height:10px;
}

.article:hover .image {
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

For a JSFiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/DanielApt/ts8ahznd/) (you might need to click *Run* to see the bug appear)

The issue is that when starting the page we do not see the background-image. When you hover over `.article` then the image suddenly appears! When hovering out the image remains (as expected).

It is as if the browser only repaints the background-image when the user hovers?

[image: The image does not display on initial page load]

*The image does not display on initial page load*

[image: The image displays on a mouse hover, the image will remain afterwards.]

*The image displays on a mouse hover, the image will remain afterwards*

How can we display the background-image by default?

**Fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/ykrbe4zy/**

Comment: Try changing `style='background-image` to just `style='background`

Comment: Detect if the user is using internet explorer.  If they are, send popups saying not to.

Comment: @JamesKorden, I wish, I wish…

Comment: @JamesKorden: Its always better to make the web application which works on all Browser!!! For a small issue like Background Image, you don't want to Remove IE users, It was a small fix, check my answer

Comment: I still contest that my 100% serious comment is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key problem with image is that you're applying the `display: table-row;` for the image which seems not supported by IE properly.

Use `display: inline-block;` instead:

```
.image{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[here's the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ts8ahznd/8/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I'll now to try out this solution in our more thorough production environment, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Change below code

**from :**

```
header, .image {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    background: red;
    height: 10px;
}
```

**TO**

```
header, .image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

header {
    background: red;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ts8ahznd/7/

**Updated Code:**

**CSS**

```
 * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
  }
  .article {
      height: 200px;
      background: aliceblue;
  }
  .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
  }
  header, .image {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  header {
      background: red;
      height: 40px;
  }
  .article:hover .image {
      opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="article">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="image" style='background-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Left_side_of_Flying_Pigeon.jpg");'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer, I'll test it out now (in our very slow production env).

Comment: It worked, thank you. I did feel that @C-linkNepal's answer was more concise, so I've awarded him the correct answer.